# Clojure function throws casting exception on println? How can one keep function & correct error?

Tags: clojure, long-integer

Outside of the function, the code works as expected, but in the following code it returns exception on a test site [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn]

How can I keep the function structure & get the results to print?

```
(defn sumTerm [hi lo] 
(if (< hi lo)
    (0)
    (let [
        terms (quot hi lo)
        tb (+ terms 1)
    ]
    (quot (* lo terms tb) 2)
    )             
))

let [
     ln 27
     a (sumTerm ln 4)
     b (sumTerm ln 7)
     abc (- (+ a b) (sumTerm ln 28))
 ]
 (println " abc= "(str abc))
```

Comment: What should this code do? Can you provide some test cases (input -> expected output)? And what is (now not defined) `ln`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot work as expected unless you never hit the `(< hi lo)`'s "then" branch, because you're trying to call `0` as a function by wrapping it in parentheses.

Try replacing `(0)` with just `0`.

Comment: That solved the issue. Thank you! My real function now resolves all Euler test cases. ;-)